# what happens to the objects created and the local references in a Method where exception is thrown

Tags: java, garbage-collection

I was analyzing a situation of memory leak in my project,couldn't find the exact cause why this is happening only some times,where i can see some exceptions related to JRMP connection establishment.

I wonder what happens to those objects & local reference created by the Method where exception is thrown,Will they be GCed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whether an exception is thrown or the method returns normally doesn't change anything: if an object is not referenced by a local variable on a thread stack anymore, and is not reachable from any root (i.e. there is no chain of references from a static variable or a local variable on a thread stack leading to this object), then the object becomes eligible to garbage collection, and will eventually be collected.